ArrowNotImplementedError: Got S3 URI but Arrow compiled without S3 support
I am trying to read only two columns from .parquet file, given in S3, using lambda AWS.
The function process_object given in the lambda, try to read huge parquet file of R50 flux. Each partition in S3, has 10 parquet files, each has MB huge size.
Look the P.J

The lambda has limititations, that it can not deal with huge file, because of memory.
I tried to optimise it when reading parquet file using PyArrow library, to read only needed columns.
elif object_name.endswith(".parquet"):  
    rows = []
    if flow_name == "R50":
        path = "s3://" + bucket_name + "/" + object_prefix
        dataset = ds.dataset(path, format="parquet")
        table = dataset.to_table(columns=["nom_archive", "nom_fichier"])
        filtered_table = table.filter(
            (table["nom_archive"].is_valid()) & (table["nom_fichier"].is_valid())
        )
        filtred_df = filtered_table.to_pandas()
        rows = filtred_df.to_dict(orient="records")
     df = pd.DataFrame(rows)

But, it causes this error message :

[ERROR] ArrowNotImplementedError: Got S3 URI but Arrow compiled
without S3 support

How can I deal with that please ? Is there any other method to optimize reading parquet file in my lambda ?
Thank you,
